# MAUI Healthkit Checking Sharing Permissions

Tags: ios, xamarin, maui, healthkit

I want to check the healthkit read permissions given by an IOS device.

Inside the appdelegate I have the following. The app loads and brings up the permissions and they save to the device.

```
private HKHealthStore healthKitStore = new HKHealthStore();

public override void OnActivated(UIApplication application)
{
    ValidateAuthorization();
}

private void ValidateAuthorization()
{
 var restingHeartRate = HKQuantityType.Create(HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.RestingHeartRate);

 var typesToWrite = new NSSet();

 var typesToRead = new NSSet(new[] { restingHeartRate});

 healthKitStore.RequestAuthorizationToShare(
          typesToWrite,
          typesToRead,
          ReactToHealthCarePermissions);
}

void ReactToHealthCarePermissions(bool success, NSError error)
{
   var access = hks.GetAuthorizationStatus(HKQuantityType.Create(HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.RestingHeartRate));
    if (access.HasFlag(HKAuthorizationStatus.SharingAuthorized))
    {
        
    }
}
```

the returned value from GetAuthorizationStatus can be either, Shared, Notdetermined and Notshared. There's no differentiation between read and write authorization. The code above shows resting heart rate is not shared, even though it has read access.

If I change the above to:

```
 var typesToWrite = new NSSet(new[] { restingHeartRate});

 var typesToRead = new NSSet();
```

Then the GetAuthorizationStatus returns as being shared but, I don't want write access, I only want read. Is there another way to check read authorization status only, accurately?

Answer (score 0):

`HKAuthorizationStatus` gives you write authorization status only.
Due to privacy reasons, there is no way to determine read authorization status, as outlined in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/protecting_user_privacy

> For example, a user could let your app read step count data, but prevent it from reading blood glucose levels. To prevent possible information leaks, an app isn’t aware when the user denies permission to read data. From the app’s point of view, no data of that type exists.

Comment: That makes no sense to me. If I request access to read step count or resting heart rate why can't I know if I'm allowed it? I don't specify any access to blood glucose or other information so I'm not interested in knowing.  What's the point in asking for read access at all?

Comment: You ask for read access so that you're able to query data from HealthKit. If the user decided to grant read access to your app for a given data type, the query will return the data available in the HealthKit store. If the user decided to deny read access, the query will return nothing as if there is no data of the requested type in the HealthKit store. This is by design to protect the user's privacy.

Comment: It's explained here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/1614154-authorizationstatusfortype

Comment: I have already read the documentation. It’s still stupid in my opinion. It’s unnecessary to keep private whether or not someone has said no to read access. Keeping the actual data private when the user has said so is obvious. Personally, I think Apple should change it

Answer (score 0):

You can't check the user's read permission status, Apple's official documentation says:

> To help prevent possible leaks of sensitive health information, your
> app cannot determine whether or not a user has granted permission to
> read data. If you are not given permission, it simply appears as if
> there is no data of the requested type in the HealthKit store. If your
> app is given share permission but not read permission, you see only
> the data that your app has written to the store. Data from other
> sources remains hidden.

For more details, you can check the official documentation:

[authorizationStatusForType | Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/1614154-authorizationstatusfortype?language=objc#:%7E:text=To%20help%20prevent,sources%20remains%20hidden.)